# undefined reference to function but my function is a part of a library that I link in cmake with the command target_link_libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, undefined-reference

I have a project which need CVB so I link the CVB libraries in my Cmake and the headers with some include in my main.hpp. Nevertheless functions of CVB which are in these libraries are undefined and I don't understand why. If someone may help me, thanks.

Comment: Incorrect order of linking possibly. Please show us the relevant parts of your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding this information using a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it was because i must run it on x32 and no in x64